# Find all regex occurences in column

Tags: mysql

Basically, I'm trying to extract all anchor tags from a column that contains blog post content that is partially HTML.

The regex can be super simple, so this would be sufficient `<a[^>]*>[^<]*</a>`, but unfortunately I'm not that familiar with more complicated SQL queries that contain loops and such.

Hope somebody can help and thanks in advance.

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?  MySQL is not the best too for a regex find all operation.

Comment: Version 5.7, it's a WordPress website where I'm trying to list all links in wp_posts > post_content. The full anchor tag html is a requirement because I also need the `rel` and `target` attributes as well for further analysis.